Uninstalling a mysterious version 3.8 of Python that is not on my Programs list or PATH environment variable of my Windows 11
So I am trying to do a project recently that requires the use of Python 3.9. This is the version of Python I always had installed on my Windows 11. For some reason, the system decided to use the 3.8 version and I am not sure how to switch it back.

I went to my Command Prompt and used py --list and it lists 2 versions of Python that is found: 3.8 and 3.9. I then went to the Control Panel and the Programs and Features section and I could not find a 3.8 for me to uninstall. It only lists a 3.9.6 version. I checked the PATH user variables and sure enough, the path stated there is only for 3.9. I have no idea where the v3.8 came from and I am not sure how to have the system just use the 3.9 version without messing up the system.
